# Firebase Dynamic Link DMARC Error Android

Tags: android, dkim, firebase-dynamic-links, yahoo-mail, dmarc

I have been using Firebase Dynamic Links in my app for users to send email invites to other users. However, a user reported that using a Yahoo! email blocks her email invites with this error:

> 550 5.7.1 unauthenticated email from yahoo.com is not accepted due to domain's DMARC policy. Please contact the administrator of yahoo.com domain if this was a legitimate mail. Please visit https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2451690 to learn more about the DMARC initiative.

However when reading about the said DMARC initiative, it needs to set some DKIM keys to the domain of the sender, in which we don't have control since the user is just using Yahoo! This is the code I used to send Firebase Dynamic Links.

```
            Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder(getString(R.string.invitation_title))
                .setMessage(mInviteMessage.getText())
                .setDeepLink(Uri.parse("http://www.crimeresponder.com/invitation?access=" + CRLUser.Roles.getCode(mAccessDropdown.getSelectedItem().toString())
                + "&stationId=" + stationId
                + "&city=" + city))
                .setCallToActionText(getString(R.string.invitation_cta))
                .build();
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
```

Comment: If you're using the first user's email address as the FROM address of the invitations you're sending, that's disallowed unless the owner of the domain (in this case Yahoo!) allows it.  That's the whole point of DMARC.  Switch to using email addresses on a domain that you control.

Comment: @PeterGoldstein can you elaborate on the "first user" part of your comment? What workaround can I do if we don't have our own domain?

Comment: The first user in my comment is the 'inviter'.  You are not allowed to send email with a From address on a domain without the domain owner's consent.  That's the whole point of DMARC.  Yahoo hasn't given you consent, so you can't send email from <user>@yahoo.com addresses.  So if you're using the 'inviter' address as the From for your invitation email, and the 'inviter' address is a Yahoo address, you'll be blocked.  DMARC is becoming more and more widespread, so expect similar issues with Gmail, etc. soon.  In short, if you're sending email you're going to need your own domain.